# Scheme/Racket R5RS. How to make a given list and a value input, into a nested list of functions

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

Im sorry if this is a very newby question, but i could not find a direct answer. I am give a task to define a chain-all function, giving init value and list of functions fn
When i call `chain-all 0 (list f g h)`
The output is supposed to `(f (g (h 0)))`
I am way off currently, but so far i have

```
(define (chain init fns)    
  (if (null? fns) init  
      (cons (car fns) (chain init (cdr fns)))))
```

Comment: Hint: What you currently have is `(cons f (cons g (cons h 0)))`, whereas what you want is `(list f (list g (list h 0)))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You build list using `cons`, so it's flat. And you want nested list, so change:

```
(cons (car fns) (chain init (cdr fns)))))
```

to

```
(list (car fns) (chain init (cdr fns)))))
```

Also keep in mind when you evaluate this function from REPL for testing purposes, you should probably use `quote` instead of `list`:

```
> (chain 0 `(f g h))
```

Comment: No, it should be either `(list f g h)` or `\`(,f ,g ,h)`. Your example of `\`(f g h)` will contain the _symbols_ `f`, `g`, and `h`, rather than the actual function objects.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young - in real application, you are right, it should be `list`. I was talking about REPL and simple manual testing.